# EditorTemplates

Tags: asp.net-mvc, telerik, grid, mvc-editor-templates

I can not understand why in "EditorTemplates" the data are not available for viewing.
Although for editing all works fine.

```
    @model site_NorvuzIS.ref_IppSpecialist.vIppJournalDTO

    @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.PersFio)
    @Html.Display("PersFio")

    <br/>

    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.PersFio)
    @Html.Editor("PersFio")
```